# Open Fancybox slideshow from link

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've had a look and don't think this is covered yet on the site.  I am looking to open a Fancybox window from my site that will automatically play a slideshow starting from the 1st image.  I also need to be able to still click on a thumbnail in my gallery to open that singular image in the standard way.

Is this possible?

Can you help?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: You need to add a slider inside of the fancybox markup.

Comment: Hi Christopher - thanks but what do you mean - do you have an exaple I can see?

Comment: It says video but it's really a fancybox. Click on the image and check the source. http://staging.oncallinteractive.com/TheCL/photo-page.html

Comment: I used the http://nivo.dev7studios.com/ plugin inside fancy box, but you can use whatever slider you like :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean the built in Fancybox gallery. So, to group images into a gallery just add a `rel` tag with the gallery name, like this ([ref](http://fancybox.net/howto)):

HTML

```
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="image_big_1.jpg"><img src="image_small_1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="image_big_2.jpg"><img src="image_small_2.jpg" alt=""/></a>   

<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group2" href="image_big_3.jpg"><img src="image_small_3.jpg" alt=""/></a> 
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group2" href="image_big_4.jpg"><img src="image_small_4.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Then initialize Fancybox on all of the links and it will automatically create two galleries with the links: group1 and group2.

```
$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();
```

This method is the same for the [older Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) and the updated [Fancybox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).